# Interpolate Between Quaternion.Slerp for rotate around player & Vector3.Lerp to keerp camera chasing the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im having an issue with the rotation of the camera around player getting too much damping. i do try to manipulate those speed value but it doesnt work at all. i think thats need something combination between slerp and lerp together, and i just dont know how. Btw im trying to create a third person game and the camera scripts make me stuck, and also i try to create my own scripts rather than using cinemachine. Really hope u guys can help me out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MouseX, MouseY;
    public Transform Player;
    public float SmoothTime;

    public float DefaultZoom = 5f;
    public float ZoomSpeed;

    Vector3 NewPosition;
    Quaternion NewRotation;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

        Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Update()
    {
        MouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        MouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 100f * Time.deltaTime;

        MouseY = Mathf.Clamp(MouseY, -75, 75);

        DefaultZoom += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        DefaultZoom = Mathf.Clamp(DefaultZoom, 3f, 9f);
        DefaultZoom = Mathf.Lerp(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position), DefaultZoom, ZoomSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        NewRotation = Quaternion.Euler(MouseY, MouseX, 0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, NewRotation, Time.deltaTime * SmoothTime);


        NewPosition = Player.position - (transform.forward * DefaultZoom);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, NewPosition, Time.deltaTime * SmoothTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working as expected? If the movement is fine but the rotation is too slow then use separate factors for both and adjust them individually

Comment: yes, the rotation is the real issue... like i said, i do change the value of the rotation slerp and position lerp separately... it will cause a jittery when the value greater 2x... right now both have set to 10f... if i change the value or the rotation to 20f, it doesnt change too much the damping... if i change to 25f... jittery happen...

Answer (score -1):

You are using Lerp wrong, both for rotation and position. Lerp isn't actually intended for smoothing, but is used for that purpose never the less, since it is very quick to program.

To fix your problem quickly (tho at the cost of being frame rate dependent), simply remove the `Time.deltaTime` and make sure that the smooth variable is kept between 0 and 1. The underlying reason is that `Time.deltaTime` is jumpy (or jittery) by nature and it passes that property directly to Lerp.

Comment: i have to take a try for this... it getting even worse... super jittery at all... i have play the value between 0.5f - 0.002f... i think time.deltatime have a good solution for smooth... but maybe i should use smoothdamp instead... but it still doesnt give a  good interpolate between position and rotation... also.. the z rotation also have a problem.. maybe it been effected bt gimbal... im still have no idea...

Comment: It's unfortunate that it didn't work for you. I tested the original script with your suggested value of 25, which caused jitter and my change with a value of 0.1f which stopped that issue. You might be having some additional problems that are outside of the script, like the camera being parented to something that rotates, other scipts or animators interfering or something else entirely.